# Need to increase space between TOF title and content and need to remove indent of TOC content beging?

Tags: table-of-contents

My document TOC generate looks like. I need to increase yellow space and remove Red line indent.Same thing need to do List of table  ,also.
[image]

The following code i use to some formate in TOF.

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}


\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\noaddvspace}
```

need chane expert help to chage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package. Here is an MWE, using the generally available `report` class rather than your template that I am not going to download.

```
% tocloftprob.tex SE 539396

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%%%% for the LoF
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\vspace{2cm}} % extra space below title
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} % no indent of titles

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{An illustration}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
A TABULATION
\caption{A tabulation}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have only made changes to the LoF so you can see how they compare with the default LoT. Read the documentation (`texdoc tocloft`) for more information.